# MouseEvent in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to make my own button in flash application. Here is some code:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Out);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);

...

private function Over(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    addChild(overImage);
}

private function Out(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeChild(overImage);
}
```

When mouse is over this button, overImage is blinking. Looks like `Over` and `Out` are calling each frame. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the mouse is positioned in a point where `overImage` will appear, then that child object will cause a `MOUSE_OVER` event on itself and thus a `MOUSE_OUT` event on its parent. The parent `MOUSE_OUT` will remove the `overImage` from the display list and that wil cause again a `MOUSE_OVER` over the parent, startin the loop once again and making the `overImage` to blink.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this with Flex; why not use a [Flex Button](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html)?

The MouseOver event will fire continuously as the mouse moves.  I would perform a check before calling the addChild to see if the overImage is already parented:

```
private function Over(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   if(!overImage.parent){
    addChild(overImage); 
   }
}

private function Out(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(overImage.parent){
     removeChild(overImage);
    }
}
```

I suspect that will prevent the "Blinking".

Comment: That wasn't halp, but according your advices, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other guy said use ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT instead, OR set the button.mouseChildren = false.

The reason it's blinking is because MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT will for every child of that button. So if you have text, or a bg image / color, or a shine, or other elements inside of it, every time you roll over ANY of those parts, it's firing.

So when you add "overImage", it appears below the mouse, and that fires another mouseOut and mouseOver. Again, just use ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT, OR set mouseChildren = false

Answer (score 0):

Just consider using `MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER` and `MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT` events. They ignore component's children. Without any additional checks and ugly tricks.

And by the way, buttons support skins and states, so you can just include your image into 'over' state.